# My DHCP client server (CentOS) cant get IP from DHCP server (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, dhcp

Good day
kindly i have set up my DHCP server ( ubuntu Server) to provide IP for servers as client but the client is getting another IP out of submitted rang IP and i can't find any symptom in this matter .

would you please leave your comment ?

Thanks

DHCP Server Config (Ubuntu Server) :
/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server ---> INTERFACESv4="enp0s3"

/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf --->

```
subnet 192.168.56.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 192.168.56.151 192.168.56.160;
    option routers 192.168.56.177;
    option domain-name-servers 192.168.56.188;
}
```

DHCP Client Config (CentOS):
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3

```
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=enp0s3
UUID=97e2da34-0d9e-4d5a-a47e-45e7c1b67e9d
DEVICE=enp0s3
ONBOOT=yes
```

Answer (score 1):

It was a wrong configuration on VirtualBox and you should uncheck the `DHCP Server` checkbox like shown in the following screenshot:

[image]